# how to correctly converter seconds to minute/hour with luxon ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, converters, luxon

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

currently I have a function that works correctly

```
function numberToHms(numbers) {
  let hms;
  let number = numbers;
  number = Number(number);

  const h = Math.floor(number / 3600);
  const m = Math.floor((number % 3600) / 60);
  const s = Math.floor((number % 3600) % 60);

    const hour =
         h > 0
             ? `${h}h`
             : "";

     const minute =
         m > 0
             ? `${m}min`
             : "";

    const second =
         s > 0
             ? `${s}${
                   m === 0 && h === 0
                       ? `seconde`
                       : `sec`
             : "";

     if (h > 0) {
         hms = hour + minute;
     }

     if (m > 0 && h === 0) {
         hms = minute + second;
     }

    if (s > 0 && m === 0 && h === 0) {
         hms = second;
     }

     return hms;
 }
```

render

```
<p>{numberToHms(24)}</p>
```

so my problem and the next one I would like to replace this function to use luxon directly

if you have any ideas, thank you

Neff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function numberToHms(number) {

const duration = Duration.fromObject({ seconds: number});

const minutesSeconds = duration.toFormat('mm:ss'); //to convert it to Hours minutes and seconds use this duration.toFormat('hh:mm:ss');
console.log(minutesSeconds);

return minutesSeconds
}
```

Comment: thx bro , it's a good start, you have idea , if i want the format 1h 1min 1sec ? thx

Comment: The comment mentioned I think should work. Like this: duration.toFormat('hh:mm:ss')

Comment: sorry bro I expressed myself badly, I start again, with your example, if i have 130 in second ,I get the answer in the following format "00:02:10". and I would rather receive it in the following format "2min 10sec". thx man

Comment: Could you try this out: duration.toFormat("m'min' s'sec'"); and reply to me if it works for you?

Comment: it works very very well, thx to mush, can I continue to bother you with another question?

Comment: Go on, I will respond you as soon as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250370/discussion-between-juljo-shahini-and-neff).

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

````js
import React from 'react';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

function secondsToHMS(seconds) {
  const duration = DateTime.fromMillis(seconds * 1000);
  return duration.toFormat('hh:mm:ss');
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{secondsToHMS(3661)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}```
And if you want to custom the format you could do something like
```javascript
return duration.toFormat('hh hours, mm minutes and ss seconds');
````